# Как я могу запускать DialogFragment после загрузки Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-dialog

Есть DialogFragment который должен запускаться при открытии Activity, но возникла проблема, видно тормоза, думаю из-за того что DialogFragment грузиться вместе с Activity. Как сделать что-бы DialogFragment запускался после полной загрузки Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну попробуйте в потоке запустить с задержкой

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      //do time consuming operations
      });
    } 
}).start();
```

Или так:

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // тут вставляем то что трэба
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: 1 вариант работает только добавил Thread.sleep(100), спасибо

Comment: вызвать в onResume(), должно и без всяких задержек и дополнительных потоков работать

Comment: @keekkenen хорошо попробую